# Create a CDF from multiple experiment runs

Tags: distributions, modeling, cumulative-distribution-function

[image]

I have time series data from a series of experiments plotted above. I am trying to fit a cumulative distribution function to it. The time series can each be of different lengths and because of how the experiment works do not have equal time steps. All values lay between 0 and 1. X are the time steps and Y are the values.

What is the best approach to turn the data into a model that takes an X and returns a Y from the distribution?

I can fit a model to it easily (below). Roughly the results are $x^5$.

[image]

When I try to force it to a SmoothKernalDistribution however, the results don't look like the data at all so I suspect I'm doing something wrong.

[image]

The data I used can be found below.

```
{{{0., 0.}, {0.52, 0.}, {0.8, 0.3}, {0.9, 0.56}, {0.95, 0.75}, {0.98, 0.89}, {0.98, 0.91}, {0.99, 0.96}, {1., 0.97}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.69,0.}, {0.81, 0.44}, {0.89, 0.65}, {0.96, 0.82}, {0.98, 0.88}, {0.99,0.96}, {1., 0.98}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.47, 0.}, {0.79, 0.26}, {0.88,0.53}, {0.96, 0.75}, {0.99, 0.85}, {0.99, 0.96}, {1., 0.98}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.58, 0.}, {0.79, 0.26}, {0.89, 0.59}, {0.96, 0.79}, {0.97, 0.85}, {1., 0.91}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.59, 0.}, {0.79, 0.35}, {0.88, 0.56}, {0.95, 0.77}, {0.97, 0.89}, {0.98, 0.91}, {0.99, 0.94}, {0.99, 0.96}, {1., 0.99}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.59, 0.}, {0.82, 0.34}, {0.96, 0.63}, {0.97, 0.79}, {0.99, 0.86}, {1., 0.93}},
{{0.,0.}, {0.54, 0.}, {0.79, 0.26}, {0.91, 0.57}, {0.98, 0.76}, {0.99, 0.84}, {1., 0.96}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.5, 0.}, {0.75, 0.22}, {0.86, 0.48}, {0.95, 0.76}, {0.98, 0.88}, {0.98, 0.95}, {1., 0.97}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.55, 0.}, {0.8, 0.3}, {0.95, 0.65}, {0.99, 0.78}, {1., 0.89}},
{{0., 0.}, {0.63, 0.}, {0.84, 0.34}, {0.9, 0.68}, {0.95, 0.79}, {0.98, 0.87}, {0.99, 0.91}, {1., 0.95}}}
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by a "distribution," what you are measuring, and how you are making these measurements.  The latter are important, because it sounds like you might be plotting cumulative measurements, which will cause your plotted points to be extremely positively correlated and that's important to account for.

Comment: The data from the experiments is going to be used in a large MonteCarlo simulation. I actually don't know how the measurements were made. I'm the data analyst and they were given to me from the mechanical engineer and are related to IoT devices. I forgot to account for the positive correlation I guess because you are correct.

Comment: For 4 of the 10 series a "time step" is duplicated at either .98 (series 1 and 8) or .99 (series 3 or 5). What's going on there?